# How can I scroll 2 overlapping divs at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make 2 overlapping divs both scroll instead of just the one that is on top? Normally when you scroll it will only scroll the top most div since it is blocking the one under it. But I want both to scroll.

What I want seems very simple so I'm hoping it can be done without js, but if js is needed I'll still try it.

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: You can’t do it without JS. What you can do is to ensure the scroll position is mirrored from the top element by the bottom element.

Comment: Interesting, why do need this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 .revolvContainer {
      background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      position: relative;
      height: 200vh;
    }
    
    .containerFirst {
      display: flex;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .containerSecond {
      margin-top: -100vh;
      height: 100vh;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 40;
      background-color: rgb(98, 100, 111);
    }
```

Am not sure what do you mean by scrolling both at the same time?